# C# Functions faster in time measurement after pre-calling it?

Tags: c#, function, call, stopwatch, measurement

i`m just trying to find out why functions seem to run faster after they were called once before measuring the time.

Here is a sample of my measurement code:

```
            float X = 0;
        FastMath.FireUp(); // Does nothing in this sample
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            X = FastMath.FastSin(i);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("TIME : " + watch.Elapsed );
```

And here you can see my called function:

```
        public static float FastSin(float val)
    {
        int index = 360 - ((int)val % 360);
        if(index == 360)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return -TRIGONOMETRIC_LOOKUPTABLE[index];
    }
```

So the thing is, that my measurement shows following output:

> TIME : 00:00:00.0001196

Lets fill the "FireUp" function with:

```
float x = FastSin(123);
```

Now the measured time decreased significantly:

> 00:00:00.0000015

But still, "FastCos", which wasn`t called in the FireUp function, still takes the longer time.

Two other points which i should mention:

- If I dont call the "FireUp" function, the time increases again:

  > TIME : 00:00:00.0002796
- If I fill my "FireUp" function with:

  float x = FastSin(123);
  x = FastCos(123);

  It just runs fine for both functions in the future measurement.
  Now it takes TIME : 00:00:00.0000019 for each function.

Why is that happening?

Comment: JIT Compilation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx , http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When compiling to managed code, the compiler translates your source
>   code into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), which is a
>   CPU-independent set of instructions that can be efficiently converted
>   to native code.

On the runtime MSIL code compiled (by JIT) to the binary platform dependent code. CLR compiles just used paerts of code then it will compile `FastSin` method just before it calls first time.

> The runtime supplies another mode of compilation called install-time
>   code generation. The install-time code generation mode converts MSIL
>   to native code just as the regular JIT compiler does, but it converts
>   larger units of code at a time, storing the resulting native code for
>   use when the assembly is subsequently loaded and run.

You can read more about [MSIL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tkafs1(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Compiling MSIL to Native Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The method is just in time compiled (jit).  This is why it's faster after already being called.

Comment: Do you know how to disable this kind of compilation in visual studio 2015 ? I`ve tried to disable the JIT Debugging options but still same results.

Comment: Jit compiler is part of the clr. You could pre compile with ngen.

Comment: @Zerrox96 it's normal practice to warm up methods first for performance tests and even warm up services for initialize infrastructure for large frameworks.